# Same collector current of BJT simulation

Tags: transistors, bjt

How do we simulate 2 bipolar junction transistors of the same collector current in LTspice which has different emitter base junction areas?

Comment: For transistor 2, you can put BJTs in parallel to increase the emitter base junction areas but this way, you only get integer multiples of transistor1's emitter base area

Comment: @Star The Q-card, which looks like this: `Qxxx Collector Base Emitter[Substrate Node] model [area] [off] [temp=<T>]`, is probably how it is done. LTspice supports the VBIC model. Read the docs there. The area parameter is the only area you can specify and all it does is scale the geometry with respect to the *unit device*.

Comment: The following [model parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTicp.png) are adjusted in the indicated way by `area`. (This table is from Andrei Vladimirescu's excellent book, *"The SPICE Book"*.)